# How can find Euler approximation to the solution of an ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

How can I find   the Euler appproximation $x_2$ at $t=2h$ to the solution $x$ of the intial value problem $$\frac{dx}{dt}=2x+t+1, \qquad x(0)=7$$
I know $x_1= 7+15h$, but how can I calculate   $x_2$?

Comment: Were you given any other information given that $h = (b-a)/n$?

Comment: no t=2h thats all i got

Comment: Did you mean $x_1 = 7 + 16h$?

Answer (score 0):

So you already understood how to interpret 
$$
x_{k+1}=x_k+h\cdot f(t_k,x_k), ~~\text{ where } ~~ f(t,x)=2x+t+1, 
$$
for $k=0$. Now all that is required is to apply it to $k=1$, that is, to compute $f(h, 7+15h)$ and insert it into the iteration formula
$$
x_2=7+15h+h⋅f(h, 7+15h).
$$.